# How to stub an object method with sinon?

Tags: node.js, sinon

I need to stub the sendMandrill method of the mh object.

See my file under test (mail.js):

```js
let MailHandler = require('../../modules/mail.handler.module');
...
let api = (router, parser) => {
   let send = async (req, res, next) => {
      let mh = new MailHandler();
      mh.sendMandrill();    
      ...
   }
   ...    
   return router.post('/mail/send', parser.json(), send);
}
module.exports = api;
...
```

My test (mail.spec.js):

```js
let stRequest = require('supertest');
let MailHandler = require('../../modules/mail.handler.module');
describe('my test', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
      sinon.stub(MailHandler.prototype, 'sendMandrill', () => true);
   })
   it('stubs sendMandrill!', done => {
      stRequest(app)
         .post('/mail/send')
            .end((err, resp) => {
                done();
            });
   })
})
```

Currently I'me getting the error below:

```js
TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property sendMandrill
```

Adding mail.handler.module - See below the mailHandler / sendMandrill code:

```js
module.exports = mailHandler;

function mailHandler() {
    ...
    var mandrill = require('../modules/mandrill');

    var handler = {
        sendMandrill: sendMandrill,
        ...
    };

    return handler;

    function sendMandrill() {
        mandrill.messages.sendTemplate({
            message: {...}
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the mail handler module?

Comment: @WakeskaterX why is that relevant? Think about MailHandler as a generic class which has to be instantiated, and the method that has to be stubbed is in the resulting object.

Comment: Try changing: `sinon.stub(MailHandler.prototype, 'sendMandrill', () => true);` to: `sinon.stub(MailHandler, 'sendMandrill', () => true);` To read more: https://medium.com/@alfasin/stubbing-with-sinon-4d6539caf365

Comment: Thanks @alfasin - unfortunately I get the same error.

Comment: That means that `MailHandler` doesn't have such a function. Are you sure you're importing it correctly? Try to step on it with a debugger to see how `MailHandler` looks like

Comment: Yes @alfasin, the method 'send' works properly. Regarding your previous comment, please notice the difference between MailHandler().send() and MailHandler.send(). I am trying to stub the former.

Comment: +1 for sharing the mail handler module.  The error means that `sendMandrill` does not exist on the prototype for `MailHandler` so we would need to see that code to help determine why.  (I'm guessing `sendMandrill` is implemented as an instance property)

Comment: You are using `MailHandler` as if it were a constructor `let mh = new MailHandler();`.  But it is a factory function that simply returns a POJO. Stubbing things in `MailHandler.prototype` makes no sense because the prototype is effectively never used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current approach creates a new `sendMandrill` for each and every instance created by `mailHandler` factory. You should actually call it w/o new `let mh = mailHandler()` or even better rename it to `createMailHandler` to avoid misuse.

If you want to effectively use prototype inheritance you'll need to rewrite `mailHandler` to use actually use `this` instead of a newly created object.

```
var mandrill = require('../modules/mandrill');

module.exports = MailHandler;

function MailHandler() {
    // use this instead of newly created object
    this.foo = 'bar'

    // avoid explicit return
    // return handler;
}

// set methods to prototype
MailHandler.prototype.sendMandrill = function sendMandrill() {
        // use this instead of handler here
        mandrill.messages.sendTemplate({
            message: {...}
        });
    }
```

Using the above approach you would be able to stub prototype properties via `sinon` and justify calling the constructor with `new` keyword.

**UPD**

If you have no control over `mail.handler.module` you could either use `rewire` module that allows to mock entire dependencies or expose `MailHandler` as a part of your `api` module to make it injectable.

```
api.MailHandler = require('../../modules/mail.handler.module')

let mh = api.MailHandler();
```

And then in tests

```
let oldMailHandler;

beforeAll(() => { oldMailHandler = api.MailHandler})
afterAll(() => { api.MailHandler = oldMailHandler})
beforeEach(() => { api.MailHandler = function MockMailHandler() {} })
```

Comment: Thanks @Yury Tarabanko. I don't have control over mail.handler.module so I cannot change anything there. What I need to do is to mock a dependency that the function I have to test ("send") has. "send" gets a reference to an object returned by  MailHandler() (a new instance if called with "new" or a reference to an existing object otherwise, it does not matter). I have to stub the method "sendMandrill" of that object. Are you saying that the only way to stub dependencies via sinon is through stubbing the prototype?

Comment: @Miki If you don't own `mailHandler` then I'd recommend to use `rewire` to mock entire dependency. Or make it "injectable" by doing `api.ModuleHandler = require('../../modules/mail.handler.module')` and using `let mh = api.ModuleHandler()`. then you would be able to inject whatever implementation in your tests.

Comment: Alright, I made MailHandler injectable as you suggested, and now I'm able to stub it.